# Why is my JavaFX object constructor returning null in the test file?

Tags: java, javafx, junit

I'm writing some tests for my JavaFX app. This is the class I am testing:

```java
public class Form {
    FormField[] fields;

    public Form(FormField ...fields) {
        this.fields = fields;
    }

    public boolean validate() {
        boolean isValid = true;

        for (FormField field : fields) {
            isValid = field.validate() && isValid;
        }

        return isValid;
    }
}
```

`FormField` is a custom class I created. It extends JavaFX's `AnchorPane`. I have this test file :

```java
import com.passman.ui.components.FormField;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.testfx.framework.junit.ApplicationTest;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

public class FormTest extends ApplicationTest {
    private FormField validField1;
    private FormField validField2;
    private FormField validField3;
    private FormField invalidField;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        validField1 = new FormField("First name", false, false);
        validField2 = new FormField("Last name", false, false);
        validField3 = new FormField("Password", true, true);

        validField3.setValidator(value -> { return null; });
        validField3.getTextField().setText("123456abcde");

        invalidField = new FormField("Confirm Password", true, true);
    }

    @Test
    public void validateShouldReturnTrueIfAllFieldsAreValid() {
        Form form = new Form(validField1, validField2, validField3);

        assertTrue(form.validate());
    }

    @Test
    public void validateShouldReturnFalseIfAnyFieldIsInvalid() {
        Form form = new Form(validField1, validField2, validField3, invalidField);

        assertFalse(form.validate());
    }
}
```

All the tests are passing. However, I would like to migrate to JUnit5 so I can use the `@Nested` annotation. But when I do it (changing the JUnit import to `org.junit.jupiter.api.Test`), the test fails: all `FormField` constructor calls return null causing the `form.validate()` call to throw a `NullPointerException`. Why is that?

Maybe `TestFX` is only compatible with JUnit4?

Comment: My guess would be that ApplicationTest uses an setup method which is not called in Junit5. Check for the setup method applicable to Junit5, Before annotation is renamed to BeforeEach

Comment: Hmm, I didn't consider that maybe the start wasn't even being called. Thanks for the insight, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: (Completely irrelevant to the question, but as a minor optimisation, you can `if (!isValid) { break; }` at the end of your loop to avoid continuing evaluation once you've found one that _isn't_ valid.)

Comment: I want to validate all fields, because if validation goes wrong an error message is shown below the field.